# Condenser motor splice

Tags: electrical, hvac

I recently had the fan motor on my condenser blade replaced.  The hvac tech left the splice outside the shroud.  He used a waterproof end to secure the splice and wrapped with electrical tape.  It is exposed though where someone could come up and touch it.  Is this to code (California)?  Does this look professional?[image]?

Comment: Unless that's some kind of magic tape, assume that it's going to all unravel in a few weeks to months ...

Comment: So they say there is a waterproof splice underneath.  Is there some code I can point to?

Comment: It is unsightly and I'm concerned that a kid will play with it.  This is a rental unit.

Comment: Neat and workmanlike. NEC 110.12.

Answer (score 1):

### This isn't to Code

First off, we start at 110.12, which requires a "neat and workmanlike" installation, and this pretty clearly flunks that test since the wires could get weighted down into the fan blades with obvious bad consequences.

Second, I'd take this as a violation of 300.15, which requires splices to be in a box or other sort of enclosure (such as the motor terminal housing), save for a few exceptions that don't apply here.

Finally, I'd be asking what's under all that electrical tape for a splice...there are some definite 110.14 questions there.

Comment: @user86080 -- we express our thanks here with upvotes and accepted answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are typically the reversing wires so one motor can go CCW or CW. I dislike reversible motors for this very reason. If I really need to use one I zip tie the wires inside the shroud either to the motor itself or the tube that carries the rest of the wires. He was probably was not sure which way it was going to go in the end and didn’t want to take the 4 screws off again to tuck it inside the shroud. Other than neatening up the wires inside the shroud there isn’t much else you can do with the reversing motors.